# Forge Viewer: Need to hide all the elements like in isolated view

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Using the `isolate()` method I can isolate few elements and hide everything else like this: 

`viewer.isolate([65, 80, 83, 92]);`

[image]

But is it possible to hide all the elements like the hidden elements of the isolated view?

I tried doing `viewer.isolate([]);`

But that would show all the elements instead.

What I need instead is to be able to hide all the elements and show only the semi-transparent view like in the isolated state.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution might be as follow ...

```
var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree
var rootId = instanceTree.getRootId()
viewer.hide(rootId) // hidding root node will hide whole model ...
```

Comment: This seems to be a quick solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

For a list of dbIds, you can call the following (for each dbId):

```
var n = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.nodeAccess.nodes[dbId];
viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(n, true);
```

To show again, just replace the *setNodeOff* **true** with **false**.

Comment: This is a more useful behavior to me, than that of `viewer.isolate(...)`/`viewer.hide(...)`. Those two cancel the previous isolated/hidden nodes. BTW, if you have multiple models loaded, is preferred to access the `visibilityManager` from the model: `model.visibilityManager...` (of course, you can pass the model as a third argument to `viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(...,...,model)`). One more note is that `setNodeOff` doesn't work with a list of `dbId`s, but it works with a single `dbId`

Answer (score 2):

found an easy global setting for ghosting: Viewer3d.setGhosting(bool)

```
var viewer = NOP_VIEWER;
viewer.setGhosting(false);
```

this will turn off the visibility of the non-isolated elements completely